# problemas ao passar dados para o EditText Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou tendo problema em carregar dados de uma tabela do sqlite e enviar esses dados para os EditText, o que posso estar fazendo errado, quando eu vou abrir a tela retorna essa mensagem no log Cat

```
11-03 06:43:30.721 14420-14420/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.



package routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.Dao.PessoaDao;
import routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.models.Pessoa;

/**
 * Created by rodrigo on 01/11/16.
 */

public class DadosCadastrais extends AppCompatActivity {
     private EditText edtNome ;
     private EditText edtCnpjCpf ;
     private EditText edtRgIe ;
     private EditText edtCep;
     private EditText edtUf ;
     private EditText edtCidade;
     private EditText edtBairro ;
     private EditText edtEndereco;
     private EditText edtnumero ;
     private EditText edtComplemento;
     private EditText edtFoneComercial;
     private EditText edtFoneResidencial;
     private EditText edtFoneCelular;
     private  EditText edtEmail ;
     private PessoaDao pessoaDao;
     private Pessoa pessoa;
     ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados_cadastrais);
    }

    public void carregarDados() throws SQLException {
            pessoa = pessoaDao.queryForId(1);
            edtNome= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
            edtNome.setText(pessoa.getNome());
    }

}
```

Comment: Mas o APP está dando crash? Essa mensagem não parece ser causada pelo seu editText

Comment: talvez a query esteja muito pesada e pelo fato dela rodar na UI Thread deve estar dando lentidão e travamento.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson, seria melhor eu carregar essa query em outra classe?

Comment: Então...é só uma teoria. Não sei muito bem o que pode ser, porque esse erro de Choreografer tem ligação com a parte visual, mas como a query é chamada antes de invocar o edt, então pode ser que ela esteja pesada. Pode ser também muitos outros erros. Aqui pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat

Comment: se voce for carregar os dados em outra classe, vai ter que usar uma Asynctask, por exemplo.
Pelo que vi, não acho que deve ser problema na query, porque voce usa o sqlite...

Comment: @Mr_Anderson, isso estou usando sqlite, vou tentar então com AsyncTask? mas uma pergunta da forma que estou fazendo está certo para carregar os dados  para os EditText?

Comment: como tá carregando poucos dados do sqlite, não precisa fazer async. Eu achei que fosse uma query em banco externo. Erro meu...
Os dados estão sendo carregados certos...eu só colocaria separado cada funcionalidade. um lugar só pra cast e outro só pra carregar e valorizar.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson, consegui resolver. obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema 
eu não estava passando a conexão do banco de dados, ai quando estava instanciado o mesmo ele criava uma nova referencia.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados_cadastrais);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(DadosCadastrais.this);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                pessoa= pessoaDao.queryForId(1);
                edtNome= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
                edtNome.setText(pessoa.getNome());

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }).start();




}
```